# A question on the upper bound of the limit supremum

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

My question is:

> Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers.
>   Prove that for every $\epsilon > 0$ and every $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there are $n_1, n_2\geq N$ such that 
>   $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n \leq x_{n_{1}}+\epsilon, \qquad x_{n_{2}}-\epsilon\leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n. $$

Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that given $\epsilon>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$, 
$x_{n_{1}}+\epsilon<v$ for every $n_{1}\ge N$, where $v=\lim \sup x_{n}$.

Then $x_{n_{1}}< v-\epsilon$ for $n_{1}\ge N$, and therefore $V_{N}=\sup\{x_{n}:n\ge N\}\le v-\epsilon$.

Since $v=\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}V_{k}$, this implies that $v\le v-\epsilon$, which gives a contradiction.

A similar argument applies for the $\lim\inf x_{n}$.

Comment: Let me just see if I am understanding this argument correctly. We have $x_{n_{1}}<v-\epsilon$, so for large enough $n_{1}$ all the terms of this sequence are less than the $\lim \sup x_n-\epsilon$ so now for a larger $n\geq N$ we take the sequence of its sup points which would have to be less than or equal to that. From there did you take the limit of both sides?

Comment: $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}V_N\leq \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} v - \epsilon$ ? Or do you just know since this set of supremum points is monotone decreasing it will converge to the lim sup since the sequence in bounded?

Comment: Since $x_{n_{1}}<v-\epsilon$ for $n_{1}\ge N$, $v-\epsilon$ is an upper bound for $\{x_{n}:n\ge N\}$, and therefore $V_{N}=sup\{x_{n}:n\ge N\}\le v-\epsilon$.  Then, as you point out, I'm using that $\{V_{k}\}$ is monotone decreasing to conclude that $v=lim_{k\to\infty} V_{k} \le v-\epsilon$.

Comment: Great thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: According to the definition of $\sup$ and $\inf$ there exist $n_1,n_2 \geqslant N$ with 
$$x_{n_1}>\sup_{n\geqslant N} x_n - \epsilon, \qquad x_{n_2}<\inf_{n\geqslant N} x_n + \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume the opposite and derive a contradiction: for example, for the $\limsup$, suppose there were some $\epsilon>0$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for every $m\geq N$,
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n>x_{m}+\epsilon.$$

Compare $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ with $\sup\limits_{m\geq N}(x_m+\epsilon)$; after some easy manipulations, you'll see that $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ would have to be greater than itself.